# Based on multiple criterias on parent's siblings

Tags: xpath

I would like to know if I can combine at the same time an XPath looking for the previous sibling of a certain class with a certain text and at the same time a sibling at the same level with a certain text.

For example I would like to find the following cells:

```
<td class="sdawatt_booknow"><a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160832)">Book</a></td>
```

by looking up a sibling of class `sdawatt_hrdcell` containing the text `Spin` preceded by a td of class `sdawatt_banner` with the text `Monday - 16 September 2013`.

Or the following td:

```
    <td class="sdawatt_booknow"><a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160864)">Book</a></td>
```

if we look for the date of the 'Friday - 13 September 2013'.

Is this something doable in Xpath ?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="sdawatt_outer">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Time</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Class</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Level</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Spaces</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Location</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Instructors</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Tags</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Info</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_hdrcell">Book</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="sdawatt_banner">Friday - 13 September 2013</td>
    </tr><tr class="sdawatt_classrow">
        <td class="sdawatt_time">07:45-08:15</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_classname">Boxing</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_level"> </td>
        <td class="sdawatt_spaces">14 Left</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_location">Main Studio</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_resources"> Darren</td>
        <td class=" sdawatt_infotags"></td>
        <td class="sdawatt_info"><img src="https://v4.fitnessandlifestylecentre.com/webaccess/TimetableView/information.gif" class="tiptip" /></td>
        <td class="sdawatt_booknow"><a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160848)">Book</a></td>
    </tr><tr class="sdawatt_classrow">
        <td class="sdawatt_time">12:00-12:45</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_classname">Spin</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_level"> </td>
        <td class="sdawatt_spaces">8 Left</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_location">Main Studio</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_resources"> Matt</td>
        <td class=" sdawatt_infotags"></td>
        <td class="sdawatt_info"><img src="https://v4.fitnessandlifestylecentre.com/webaccess/TimetableView/information.gif" class="tiptip" /></td>
        <td class="sdawatt_booknow"><a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160864)">Book</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="sdawatt_banner">Monday - 16 September 2013</td>
    </tr><tr class="sdawatt_classrow">
        <td class="sdawatt_time">13:00-13:45</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_classname">Spin</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_level"> </td>
        <td class="sdawatt_spaces">12 Left</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_location">Main Studio</td>
        <td class="sdawatt_resources"> Marzena</td>
        <td class=" sdawatt_infotags"></td>
        <td class="sdawatt_info">
        <img src="https://v4.fitnessandlifestylecentre.com/webaccess/TimetableView/information.gif" class="tiptip" /></td>
            <td class="sdawatt_booknow"><a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160832)">Book</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you bit clear this a more?

Answer (score 2):

```
//tr[
        contains(
            td[@class="sdawatt_banner"],
            "Monday - 16 September 2013")
    ]
    /following-sibling::tr[
                           contains(
                               td[@class="sdawatt_classname"],
                               "Spin")
                          ]/td[@class="sdawatt_booknow"]
```

yields

```
<td class="sdawatt_booknow">
  <a href="#" onclick="wa_class_book(160832)">Book</a>
</td>
```

Comment: @JensErat, thanks for your edit. I saw your answer briefly: cleaner and shorter as usual with your answers :) and probably sufficient for the usecase. I'm still not quite sure what "sibling of class sdawatt_hrdcell containing the text Spin" means for the OP.

Comment: I think my answer was wrong, so I deleted it. I think yours is actually meeting his requirements. I mainly missed the part that the row to match must follow one containing the date.

Comment: @pault.,@JensErat, I will check this tonight at home. Thanks for helping me.